# Drawing rotated rectangle into image

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to draw rotatec rectangle using openCV and python so far my code:

```
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(boxes[i][1:])
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
cv2.drawContours(image,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
```

where `boxes[i][1:]` is array of coordinations [xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax]

and `image` is image to draw recrangle on.

However this keeps throwing

```
   rect = cv2.minAreaRect(boxes[i][1:])
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.1) C:\bld\opencv_1520732670222\work\opencv-3.4.1\modules\imgproc\src\convhull.cpp:137: error: (-215) total >= 0 && (depth == 5 || depth == 4) in function cv::convexHull
```

Wha does it mean and how can i fix it?

Comment: What is the exact content of `boxes` ?

Comment: boxes is 2D array of rectangles, each box[i] is represented by [a,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax] location on image, a is number that does nothing for this purpse thats why i am passing boxes[i][1:]

Comment: If you *have* a box already, why are you passing it to `minAreaRect()`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [doc of `cv2.minAreaRect`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga3d476a3417130ae5154aea421ca7ead9), the function requires a pointset as input. So if you give a `(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)` tuple, it will be considered as a pointset composed of 2 single points `(xmin, ymin)` and `(xmax, ymax)`. Thus finding the rotated rectangle with minimum area, will lead to a null-area rectangle (the line segment between the 2 points), which is likely to generate the error you obtain.
I'm not 100% confident with that answer, but I guess that it might be right.

So I suggest to replace `[(xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax)]` by `[(xmin, ymin), (xmin, ymax), (xmax, ymin), (xmax, ymax)]` and test if it solves the problem...

Comment: i tried passing [(xmin,ymi),(xmax,ymax)] but didnt work either

Comment: @jejjejd are you sure about that? Because the only way I can reproduce this error is if either the numpy data type is wrong (you can convert it to a `np.float32` if that's the case), or the input is incorrectly specified. The input should be `np.array([(pt1_x, pt1_y), ..., (ptN_x, ptN_y)])` as stated in this answer.

Comment: Also @sciroccorics your comment has the second point and the third point the same. Consider adding that useful information into the answer itself and correcting the duplicate. Nice answer!

Comment: @Alexander: You are right. I've edited the answer and removed the comment.

Comment: @sciroccorics You've already got the documentation linked but a minimal working solution might be nice to throw in there :).